# Como instanciar una clase en mi Activity con métodos no estáticos

Tags: java, android

Saludo compañeros, Soy desarrollador web, y apena se podría decir que estoy empezando en Android, tengo un pequeño problema al momento de instanciar esta clase anidadas en mi activity, he visto muchos ejemplos en Google de como instanciar clases con métodos estáticos y métodos no estáticos, pero no he logrado implementar, he intentado de todas las formas posible pero no consigo dar con la forma correcta.

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que intento instanciar:
[Click aqui para ver el codigo](https://github.com/ebweb-lab/CodeExampleTele/blob/main/Codeexample.java)

Lo he intentado creando un objeto, con la palabra new etc.... Y no consigo implementar esa clase en mi activity.

Muchas gracias de manera anticipada

Esta es la clase que deseo instanciar

```
public class IncomingCallListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";
     TelephonyManager telephony;
     CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener ;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        mContext = context;
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.w("DEBUG", state);

                telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                customPhoneListener = new   CustomPhoneStateListener();
                telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,   PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        }
    }
    public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
        private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
        {
            switch (state) 
            {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }


    }       
}
```

Comment: Es más útil que agregues el código a la pregunta y especifiques el punto donde está el error.

Comment: @Lobos Solo me interesaría saber como instanciar esa clase que muestro en ese link

Answer (score 0):

Tu clase `IncomingCallListener` extiende de la clase `BroadcastReceiver` por lo tanto no se instancia propiamente, se registra. Puedes realizarlo de 2 formas:

**1) Declarar en el `AndroidManifest.xml`**

Especifica el elemento  en el manifiesto de tu app.

```
<application ....>
...
...
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallListener"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
```

Los filtros de intents especifican las acciones de emisión a las que se suscribe tu receptor.

**2) Registrar en el contexto**

Para registrar un receptor con un contexto, realiza los siguientes pasos, crea la instancia:

```
 BroadcastReceiver incomingCallListener = new IncomingCallListener();
```

Crea un `IntentFilter` y registra el receptor mediante una llamada a `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)`:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    this.registerReceiver(incomingCallListener, filter);
```

Revisa la documentación:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts?hl=es-419

Comment: Me tira error  java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }